# Removing data after different start date based on id

Tags: r

I have a data set that includes a `name`, `date` and `earliest_date`, in which some `name` will have a `earliest_date`. Now I want to remove all the data after the `earliest_date` based on `name`. And ignore those that  have `NA` in `earliest_date`. And sicne different `name` will have different `earliest_date`, I am pretty sure I can't use `filter()` with a set date. Any help will be much appericated.

Part of the data is below:

```
dput(mydata[1:10,])
structure(list(name = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e", "f", "g", 
"a", "h", "i"), Date = structure(c(13214, 
17634, 15290, 18046, 16326, 18068, 10234, 12647, 15485, 15182
), class = "Date"), earliest_date = structure(c(12647, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 12647, NA, 15552), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Desired output:
The first row will be removed as the `Date` recorded after `earliest_date`

```
dput(mydata[2:10,])
structure(list(name = c("b", "c", 
"d", "e", "f", "g", 
"a", "h", "i"), Date = structure(c(17634, 15290, 
18046, 16326, 18068, 10234, 12647, 15485, 15182), class = "Date"), 
    earliest_date = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12647, 
    NA, 15552), class = "Date")), row.names = 2:10, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `mydata %>% filter(Date < earliest_date | is.na(earliest_date))` *might* give you what you want, but without your desired output (and, perhaps, more complex input data), it's impossible to be sure.  PS: It's bad practice to name a variable with the name of an R function, class, or other object.

Comment: I have add a desire output for the reference, now I have think  all I need is to remove all the rows that `Date` after `earliest_date` based on `name`? But I haven't figure out the code yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may helps

```
mydata %>%
  filter(is.na(earliest_date) | Date<=earliest_date)

  name       Date earliest_date
1    b 2018-04-13          <NA>
2    c 2011-11-12          <NA>
3    d 2019-05-30          <NA>
4    e 2014-09-13          <NA>
5    f 2019-06-21          <NA>
6    g 1998-01-08          <NA>
7    a 2004-08-17    2004-08-17
8    h 2012-05-25          <NA>
9    i 2011-07-27    2012-07-31
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[is.na(mydata$earliest_date) | mydata$Date<=earliest_date,]
```